# How to call input data into my recharts chart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm new to coding and I'm building an elevation survey website but I am finding it very difficult to call my input data, acquired from my survey in to my recharts linechart. Please I need help on it and the tutorial videos are further complicating it, since they make use of static data and not dynamic data that changes when an input is submitted.

[Tutorial Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ccfL.png) and
[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xXc.png)